# It is possible to overload function by const specifier?

Tags: c++, function, constants, overloading

whether it is possible to overload function by const specifier. That is, we have two functions, one constant the other is not, can we say that the constant function overloaded non-const function ?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow : if you think an answer helped you, *accept* it as *accepted answer* by clicking on the tick mark near the vote-score.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per § 13.1 / 2:

It's not possible to put `const` in return-type to overload:

> Function declarations that differ only in the return type cannot be
>   overloaded.

```
int func();
const int func(); // Error
```

It's not possible to put `const` in parameter-list to overload:

> Parameter declarations that differ only in the presence or absence of
>   const and/or volatile are equivalent.

```
void func(int x);
void func(const int x); // Error
```

BUT, it's possible:

> const and volatile type-specifiers buried within a parameter type
>   specification are significant and can be used to distinguish
>   overloaded function declarations.

```
void func(int &x);
void func(const int &x); // OK
```

And, it's possible to put `const` at end of method declaration to distinguish overloads:

```
int func();
int func() const; // OK
```

Comment: +1 for few more cases where `const` can be put and define overloads.

Answer (score 4):

Yes and No.

It depends on where you put the `const` specifier.

When defining member functions, this is possible (Yes-part):

```
int f() { /*code*/ }         //invoke this function on non-const object
int f() const { /*code*/ }   //ok : invoke this function on const object
```

Note that in the absence of the *first* function, even non-const object will invoke the second function (i.e `const` member function) and in the absence of the *second* function, you wouldn't be able to invoke the first function on `const` objects!

But this is **not** possible (No-part):

```
int g() { /*code*/ }
const int g() { /*code*/ } //error: redefinition
```

irrespective of whether they're member functions or free functions.

Comment: Sorry slightly off-topic question. What possible use can a function have that returns a const value?

Comment: @AbhishekBansal: 1) Sometime it makes sense to return const reference to some internal state so that nobody could modify the object, it is like giving read-only access to the world. 2) If the object itself is const, then it often returns const reference to internal state (all standard containers define `const_reference` as nested type, which is the *return type* of many member functions). there could be many other use cases.